# foreign key constraint error in java

Tags: mysql, constraints

my java cannot execute this code, and gives me error like "cannot add key constraint"
Please Help me

```
st.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE `e166713`.`shopping` (   "
                      `idShopping` INT NOT NULL,                    
                      `idUser` VARCHAR(45) NULL,                    
                      PRIMARY KEY (`idShopping`),                   
                      INDEX `user_idx` (`idUser` ASC),              
                      CONSTRAINT `user`                             
                      FOREIGN KEY (`idUser`)                        
                      REFERENCES `e166713`.`user` (`uID`)       
                      ON DELETE NO ACTION                           
                      ON UPDATE NO ACTION)");
```

Comment: Is table user already created?

Comment: only user table created

Comment: Is uID a Varchar(45) in user table?

Comment: I would remove the java and jdbc tags because the error has nothing to do with java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could mean two things:

- Either `user` table is not created yet

or

- `uID` in `user` table is not of the same data type as `idUser` : 
  `varchar(45)`.

  The columns need to be the exact same data type in both tables.

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b89d)</kbd>

Comment: You are exactly right, it was integer in User table, I solved the problem, thanks a lot :)